# Emoji usage in a UILabel and appstore rules

Tags: iphone, unicode, app-store

Does anyone know if I use emoji unicode in an app's view if Apple considers this out of bounds? I'm not asking about enabling emoji or selling an app that is meant to enable emoji.

And example of the code - which is placing an NSString into a tableViewCell NSLabel:

```
if([combatCurrentHp intValue] <= [combatMaxHp intValue] / 2) {
    characterStats = [characterStats stringByAppendingString:@" \uE022"];
}
```

This makes an emoji heart appear in the string. Do you guys know if there is a hard and fast rule on if that would get kicked back out of the app store?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen applications that use the Emoji codepoints in the App Store, but I'm not sure if it's permitted or those apps just snuck through. I don't think there is a strict policy on this.

Enabling the emoji keyboard however is forbidden.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up and say that I have yet to have any trouble with using emoji (or any unicode for that matter) in my apps. So it looks like it's a safe and quick way to add a splash of color if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

2 years late, but just in case anyone else is interested in this question, the official answer is that there's no problem using emoji in your UILabels.

My email to App Review team a year ago:

> Hi,
>
> I'd like to seek clarification with regard to the usage of emoji
>   within an app.
>
> Although emoji input is not enabled for non-Japanese users, all iPhone
>   can view emoji whether or not emoji input is enabled.
>
> User interface elements such as UILabel can thus display emoji if they
>   used the appropriate unicode in the text string.
>
> I'm currently working on the next update of my app where I'd like to
>   display some icons within my text labels, and I couldn't find any
>   guidelines with regard to the usage of emoji in this manner.
>
> I've attached a screenshot for your reference. I would like to check
>   if this usage is appropriate for the App Store. Much thanks!

Their response:

> Hello,
>
> We see no issues with the use of emoji within the app. Please let us
>   know if you have additional questions.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> App Review Team iOS Developer Program

Also, my app has been using the emoji for the past one year with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that enabling the Emoji keyboard is forbidden as it is enabled as standard in all Asian countries and there are dozens of apps available in the app store for unlocking it in other countries.  Why would Apple incorporate the keyboard in the system if they intended to forbid anyone from ever using it?!

Comment: Philip - there was a point at which iOS developers had no idea what would or what not get our [apps rejected](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=658535) from the AppStore. There are still plenty of things that you _can_ do in iOS that are undocumented and will get your app rejected.

To be clear, I understand that disallowing emoji apps never seemed to actually happen, but for a while developers were uncertain what would and would not be allowed in the AppStore. Time are different now and we're all much clearer. Mostly. :)